# Speakers don't control headphone volume

Tags: speakers, headphone-jack

(I'm not sure whether this question fits this site, but I'm really curious about this issue)

I had a pair of old Genius speakers that I had connected my headphones to and used their volume control for well... controlling the volume. It worked but had a lot of noise, so I decided to replace them.

I bought [these Edifier USB powered](http://www.edifier.com/int/en/speakers/m1250-compact-laptop-usb#) speakers and everything works fine except one major thing: **With headphone plugged in, I can't control the volume any more!** It seems that when headphones are plugged in to the speaker's output jack, the volume control gets out of the circuit and it just passes the sound directly from PC.

Mind you, I can still control the volume using keyboard media keys or Windows itself. But not from speakers.

**My question is:** Is it considered normal behavior of these kinds of speakers? Or mine are malfunctioning?

Comment: It is entirely up to whoever designed the speakers as to whether they put the volume control on the speaker only side or before where the audio splits to the headphone so it controls both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be a normal behaviour. I have Zebronics USB speakers with headphone outlet. But the volume of the headphones are not controlled by the speakers' volume slider, instead I have to change the volume from the OS.

It entirely depends on the build of the speakers

- If the volume keys are a part of the bridge between the speaker input and the headphone jack, they will work.
- If not, they will work for just speakers only.

Yours and mine do not have that functionality.